# Generic C# method overload resolution with parameter array

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

In the code below, I've defined two overloaded methods named `Bar`. In `Foo()`, I make three calls to `Bar`, and get an error on the third call.

The first two resolve to the expected overloads. The third however generated the following error:

`The type 'string' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Bar<T>(T, string, params object[])'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'string' to 'System.Exception'.`

Clearly the third call is binding to "Bar()", but failing to convert the first parameter to an Exception. It's also clear that it is the second argument being a string that's throwing off the compiler. When it's not a string (case 2) the resolution is fine. But it seems obvious (to me) that the failing line should bind to "Bar()" (since the first parameter is unambiguously a string).

Can anyone explain why the compiler is using this binding? I would consider creative workarounds, but what I'm really looking for is an explanation of why this is happening. I spent some time with the C# language specification, but failed to find (i.e. gave up on) a clear answer. Obviously I can rename one of the `Bar` methods, or provide named arguments, or mark one of the parameters `ref`... but none of these is ideal for my specific scenario.

Not that it's relevant, but I have written Java code that does exactly this, and the compiler had no problem.

The code:

```
public void Bar(string s, params object[] ps) { } // Call this "Bar()"
public void Bar<E>(E e, string s, params object[] ps) where E : Exception { } // Call this "Bar<T>()"

public void Foo()
{
    Exception e;
    Object o1, o2;

    Bar(e, "fmt {0}", o); // Resolves fine, as expected
    Bar("fmt {0} {2}", o1, o2); // Also resolves as expected
    Bar("fmt {0} {2}", "bar", o1); // Error!
}
```

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965423/c-sharp-generic-overload-compiler-cant-determine-correct-call

Comment: But that question is dealing with an ambiguity. In this case the compiler and I agree that there is a binding, we just disagree on which one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that overload matching does not consider constraints. As to is this in the C# spec, I'm not completely sure. The matching always uses the most specific option and string as generic `T` is always more specific than string as `Object` (since it's matching the actual type and not a child type). See [Constraints are not part of the signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx) on Eric Lippert's blog.

To make this work, if the constraint of exception is needed, use `void Bar(Exception E, ...)` if possible.

Comment: That's interesting about constraints being ignored. But doesn't the first argument being a string make the non-generic a better match? I mean, it's binding to a method that causes a failure, instead of one which wouldn't. Y'know?

Comment: Since the second argument of the first `Bar` is an optional object, matching the second one is more specific. `Bar(string as T, string, ...)` is more specific than `Bar(string, string as Object, ...)`. I guess you could consider it the other way, but the compiler team wrote it the first way. Eric Lippert (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/) might have something to say on what that's the case. The take away, string as `T` is more specific than string as `Object`.

Comment: @Travis Looks like he does.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx

Comment: That blog post was great. The comment thread get really heated! I'll need some time to digest it, but this was a huge help. Thanks @climbage and Travis.

Answer (score 2):

`Bar("fmt {0} {2}", "bar", o1);` // Error!
By specificity priority, it looks for method signature where second parameter is string (string is more specific than object), and then tries to resolve Type argument, and it could not. To illustrate it, try to replace third call as:

```
Bar("fmt {0} {2}", (object)"bar", o1); // Now it is fine for compiler!
```